# Invoke setState after function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that setState is async, but is there anyway (without Redux) to invoke setState after the executing another function before like below:

```
handleOpenUpdateItem = (item) => {
    const { getImageByItemId } = this.props;
    getImageByItemId(item.id);
    this.setState({ updateMode: true, item });
  };
```

Greetings!

Comment: I think `getImageByItemId` is asynchronous(or it contains some asynchrounous functions)

Comment: You can use `promise` in this situation.

Comment: @PranavCBalan yes it's connected to redux and makes call to backend

Comment: @Ernesto :  move this statement  `this.setState({ updateMode: true, item });` to the callback or use Promise

Comment: I think `componentWillReceiveProps` is the ideal hook to set this `state` where one could be certain that `state/prop` is updated..

Comment: Can you please share the code of `getImageById`?

Answer (score 1):

Turn your `handleOpenUpdateItem` to an `async` function. Then you can write synchronous code inside of it.

```
  async handleOpenUpdateItem(item) {
       const { getImageByItemId } = this.props;
       const item = await getImageByItemId(item.id); // wait for the call to the backend to finish
       this.setState({ updateMode: true, item }); 
  };
```

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention that this is async function - getImageByItemId

Comment: @Ernesto Shouldn't be a problem. You can await an async function.

Answer (score 1):

As it's already mentioned in comments, you could use callbacks to make sure that `this.setState` is executed after your function finishes (using `Promises` or `async/await` would be great options too). This is the examlpe of how it could be implemented:

```
  getImageByItem = (id, callback) => {
    // Do something here
    // And return your image, or anything you want through callback like so:
    callback(yourImage)
  }

  handleOpenUpdateItem = (item) => {
    const { getImageByItemId } = this.props;
    getImageByItemId(item.id, (image) => {
      this.setState({ updateMode: true, item });
    });
  };
```

So you change your `getImageByItem` function to include callback, and then in the `handleOpenUpdateItem` you use this callback and setState inside it.

**EDIT FOR 2019**

As @Levitator Imbalance mentioned below, it's probably better to use `Promises`, so you could implement it like so:

**Without async/await:**

```
getImageByItemId = (id) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Do something with your id/image, then resolve
    resolve()
    // Or reject when some error happens
    reject()
  })
}

  handleOpenUpdateItem = (item) => {
    const { getImageByItemId } = this.props;
    getImageByItemId(id)
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({ updateMode: true, item });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        // ... handle your reject here
      })
  };
```

Or you could use `async/await` like so:
**Async/Await:**

```
getImageByItemId = (id) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Do something with your id/image, then resolve
    resolve()
    // Or reject when some error happens
    reject()
  })
}

handleOpenUpdateItem = async (item) => {
  const { getImageByItemId } = this.props;
  let something = await getImageByItemId(item.id)
  // or just:
  // await getImageByItemId(item.id)
  this.setState({ updateMode: true, item });
};
```

Comment: come on, 2019 is here) It is better to use **Promise** :)

Comment: @Levitator Imbalance, you're totally right, my bad! Edited to show both **Promise** and **Async/Await** ;)

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState()` being async means that you cannot normally execute things *after* it and expect them to happen only after the setState had completed its course. Doing things before the setState and then calling setState (exactly like you did) will work out of the box.

Comment: That means that one of the functions before it (probably `getImageById`) is asnyc, it's not a feature of `setState()`.

Comment: excatly so how to deal with it? Maybe I should refactor the code... to have this image somehow assigned to item before invoking this handler. But I wanted to fetch the item only for particular item, do not fetch all items for all items visible on the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could make handleOpenUpdateItem async and use await for getImageByItemId.

Comment: don't have reps to comment :S